# ARM GIC v3 configuration to use GICR_ registers

Tags: assembly, arm, interrupt, fast-model

I am trying to configure timer interrupt for Kite processor on Fastmodel.

I have enabled `GICD` to enable timer interrupt and it is also updating as pending once timer is 0 but to receive it to cpu interface I need to enable it in `GICR`.

When trying to enable it in `GICR`, registers are not getting updated when I run simulation. **Only `GICR_IGROUPR0` is updated. `GICR_ISENABLER0` register is not getting updated.**

Does anyone have any idea why only 1 register is able to update and not others?

Do I need any specific configuration to use GICR registers? Why only 1 register is able to update?

```
#define GICC_OFFSET 0x00
#define GICD_OFFSET 0x00
#define GICR_OFFSET 0x0100000
#define GICR_SGI_PPI_OFFSET 0x110000 // for core 0
/* CBAR is read and then the offset for Distributor and CPU Interfaces           are added */
#define GICREG(gic, reg) (*REG32(hal_arm_gic_get_base() + (reg)))

/* Redistributor control registor GICR_ */

#define GICR_CTLR (GICR_OFFSET + 0x00)

/* Redistributor for SGI and PPI for core 0*/
#define GICR_IGROUPR0 (GICR_SGI_PPI_OFFSET + 0x80)
#define GICR_ISENABLER0 (GICR_SGI_PPI_OFFSET + 0x100)
#define GICR_ICENABLER0 (GICR_SGI_PPI_OFFSET + 0x180)
#define GICR_ISPENDR0 (GICR_SGI_PPI_OFFSET + 0x200)
#define GICR_ICPENDR0 (GICR_SGI_PPI_OFFSET + 0x280)
#define GICR_ISACTIVER0 (GICR_SGI_PPI_OFFSET + 0x300)
#define GICR_ICACTIVER0 (GICR_SGI_PPI_OFFSET + 0x380)
#define GICR_IPRIORITYR(n) (GICR_SGI_PPI_OFFSET + 0x400 + (n) * 4)
#define GICR_ICFGR0 (GICR_SGI_PPI_OFFSET + 0xc00)
#define GICR_ICFGR1 (GICR_SGI_PPI_OFFSET + 0xc04)

/* distribution regs */
#define GICD_CTLR               (GICD_OFFSET + 0x000u)
#define GICD_TYPER              (GICD_OFFSET + 0x004u)
#define GICD_IIDR               (GICD_OFFSET + 0x008u)
#define GICD_IGROUPR(n)         (GICD_OFFSET + 0x080u + (n) * 4u)
#define GICD_ISENABLER(n)       (GICD_OFFSET + 0x100u + (n) * 4u)
#define GICD_ICENABLER(n)       (GICD_OFFSET + 0x180u + (n) * 4u)
#define GICD_ISPENDR(n)         (GICD_OFFSET + 0x200u + (n) * 4u)
#define GICD_ICPENDR(n)         (GICD_OFFSET + 0x280u + (n) * 4u)
#define GICD_ISACTIVER(n)       (GICD_OFFSET + 0x300u + (n) * 4u)
#define GICD_ICACTIVER(n)       (GICD_OFFSET + 0x380u + (n) * 4u)
#define GICD_IPRIORITYR(n)      (GICD_OFFSET + 0x420u + (n) * 4u)
#define GICD_ITARGETSR(n)       (GICD_OFFSET + 0x800u + (n) * 4u)
#define GICD_ICFGR(n)           (GICD_OFFSET + 0xc00u + (n) * 4u)
```

GIC V3 configuration:

```
// Check whether GICv3 system registers are available
mrc p15, 0, r7, c0, c1, 1   @ ID_PFR1
ubfx    r7, r7, #28, #4
cmp r7, #1
bne 2f

// Enable system register accesses
mrc p15, 4, r7, c12, c9, 5  @ ICC_HSRE
orr r7, r7, #( (1 << 0) | (1 << 3))
mcr p15, 4, r7, c12, c9, 5  @ ICC_HSRE
isb

// SRE bit could be forced to 0 by firmware.
// Check whether it sticks before accessing any other sysreg
mrc p15, 4, r7, c12, c9, 5  @ ICC_HSRE
tst r7, #ICC_SRE_EL2_SRE
beq 2f
mov r7, #0
mcr p15, 4, r7, c12, c11, 0 @ ICH_HCR
2:
mov R0, #0x1
MRC p15, 0, R0, c12, c12, 6
orr r0, r0, #0x1
MCR p15, 0, R0, c12, c12, 6 // Group 0 Enable
MRC p15, 0, R0, c12, c12, 7
orr r0, r0, #0x1
MCR p15, 0, R0, c12, c12, 7 // Group 1 Enable
```

Comment: `GICR_CTLR` is adding to zero?  You write to the memory mapped address, but I don't think you have the GICR base correct for your platform?

Comment: I have correct base for GICR_ because I am getting it from  PERIPHBASE and I am able to update GICR_IGROUPR0 register. Even directly in the simulator, it is not allowing to update these other GICR_ registers. So I am thinking that there should be issue somewhere in configuring GICD_ register? But when I read trm, I do not find anything relevant to GICR configuration.

Answer (score 0):

After days of search and tries, I found that it is issue in ARM Kite processor itself. ARM has released it untested to start development for partner companies.

Sad to hear this.